# not able to rebase in git

Tags: git

when I created a new branch, Master's most recent commit is A.

after I created a new branch it, some changes are done to Master, so now the most recent commit on master is B.

I made some commits to my branch, most recent commit on my fork is C.

Now I hard reset my branch to 'A' and fetched all changes using 'git fetch --all'.

and when I do 'git rebase upstream/master' it is showing some conflicts?
 why is it like that??

Answer (score 0):

you have modified the same line in both streams. There is no way git will know what you want to do. This is true whether you rebase or merge. With rebase, you are replaying a change, but the original section of the document that the change is expecting is not matching up. Git will not arbitrarily do this. You can choose a merge strategy, however, if this is your intent and use "ours" to always override the mismatch. This is not the default behaviour however.

If you figure the changes are insignificant such as whitespace or positions of braces, using a syntax aware mergetool like Beyond Compare 3 will help you get through the conflicts really fast.

If you plan to continue to rebase this work on subsequent central changes, enable rerere and it's autoupdate. This will ensure that the same conflicts are resolved the same way automatically for you.